# Jquery получить url и method  от ajax события

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, javascript

Задача состоит в том, чтобы все post запросы, сделанные через ajax, уведомляли нужный мне скрипт о том, к какому url они обращались.

Пытался так:

```
var url;
$(document).on('ajaxSuccess', function(event) {
    url = event.target.URL;
});

jQuery.post('/test', params);
```

Но в свойство `target == document`, так как я слушаю его, и в переменную url попадает текущая страница, а не которую я запрашивал.

О том, что это был post запрос, тоже нигде информации нету.
И я не могу менять на всем сайте все ajax запросы, таким образом, чтобы они бросали, например, свое состояние в глобальную переменную.

Comment: @duhon, можно обернуть некоторые тонкости яваскрипта себе на пользу:

    var ajaxWrapper = (function (ajax) {
        return function (a, b) {
            // здесь делаем любую обработку
            ajax(a, b);
        };
    })($.fn.ajax);
    $.fn.ajax = ajaxWrapper;

Но это грязный подход, которого следует избегать. Это если ничего более толкового не подскажут )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ответ очень прост, читать внимательней мануал по [jquery](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/)

`$(document).on('ajaxSuccess', func)` краткая форма от `$(document).ajaxSuccess(func)`
а это значит что вторым параметром для калбэк функции будет обьект setting, в котором есть все что нужно (url, type, и тд.)

А для всего другого извращение есть уже jQuery.ajaxPrefilter()